# The stem connects the handlebars to the...?

Tags: handlebars, stem

If this is a stem... [image: stem]... what's this?[image]
I'm asking because I need to buy a taller one so I don't have to bend over as far. It's not convenient to buy a new bike, and I already have an adjustable stem which just doesn't quite get me there.

Comment: Is this bike way too small for you or something? it looks like they left the steerer at its original length.

Comment: It isn't my bike. Just a picture from the internet

Comment: You want a bike with a taller head tube. You really want to add extra height in the frame as opposed to a long exposed steerer.

Comment: You know you could buy a stem with more height on it?

Comment: I can think of a couple of possibilities that haven't been mentioned, but are dependent  on your specific bike. You might find it beneficial to post a new question asking how to achieve the results you want with pictures of your bike rather than pictures from the internet.

Answer (score 9):

That's the fork steerer.[image]
The fork has to be replaced if you want it taller. That, or perhaps, you could add another spacer to gain a marginal 10/20mm.... Replace the forks if you're desperate.

Once you unbolt the stem, the forks can just drop out if you're not careful. Replacing the forks may not be economical to replace, and if so, I'd replace the whole bike. Good luck. :)

Actually, having said that, the steerer is already ridiculously high; I'd recommend time to replace the whole frameset, as making it too high can be dangerous, if not deadly depending on when and how it breaks. If you're going downhill and the steerer snaps from being too high and too much force going through it, it can shatter or snap, and if you fall on that, it will seriously injure you, if not killing you. Replace the frameset rather than just the forks. The whole bike looks too small for you.

Comment: A less costly alternative may be a mountain bike bar with riser design. Your current bars appear flat. A riser bar may gain you another inch. From the look of your current set-up (lots of spacers and adjustable stem maxed out) the bike is likely the wrong size.

Comment: I wonder how much seatpost is sticking out.

Comment: They sell fork steerer extenders which give you a few inches (origin8 makes one for about 20 USD), so you don't have to replace it.

Comment: @Batman I personally wouldn't trust those, but perhaps if it works for you and you're going to trust it, by all means. :)

Comment: Sheldon on extenders: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/handsup.html#extenders

Comment: Another option is to use a separate clamp to replace a threadless stem, as shown in the "Threadless Without Spacers" section of Sheldon's page, and use a quill stem in the steerer.
http://www.sheldonbrown.com/org/thorn/ is a bike that's set up that way, but also has a complete lower set of handlebars in a standard threadless stem.

Comment: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/harris/surly-rohloff/images/5-frontleft.jpg

Comment: @armb Oh dear god, that picture; two handlebars with disc and v-brake setup... :O that's terrifying, and yet... a beautiful, amazing masterpiece. 

However, his front tyre is on backwards... :3

Answer (score 7):

What you are referring to is not really a discrete component that can be swapped out.

The fork steerer tube runs through the frame 'headtube' and headset bearings. The stem clamps to the steerer tube. Between the stem and frame are a stack of spacers.

[image]

The maximum height of the stem is therefore constrained by the length of steerer tube.

Forks come with a long steerer tube to accommodate different length frame head tubes. When fitted to a bike the steerer tube is cut to length, usually with a few inches protruding from the frame, so the stem can have 1-2 inches of spacers underneath it. The length of tube left protruding depends on the type of bike.

I would guess from your picture that your steerer tube has not been cut down at all, and the stem is obviously at the top of the steerer tube. Some possible solutions:

- There are steerer tube extenders available but I'm a little reluctant to recommend you fit one as you steerer is already so long. Others here may indicate that is is OK to do so. You may also want to consult with your local bike store.
- You may be able to find a replacement stem that gives you more rise.
- As @mikes suggests in comment to another answer, replacing the bars with a set that sweep upwards from the stem clamp to raise the hand grips up may be a good solution.

Comment: But bear in mind that sitting more upright might destabilize the bike because of the diminished load on the front wheel.