# What's that thing at the bottom of the fork steerer?

Tags: mechanical

You know that slanted metal thing on the bottom of the [fork steerer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/50072/33115) that can slide around? Like, the diagonal cut thing at the end that you insert into the hole when you assemble a bicycle? What is that part called, and what is its function?

Comment: Sounds like wedge from threaded stem, and you really shouldn't have one unless it's part of the stem

Comment: A photo would help, but @ojs comment sounds reasonable.  A wedge shouldn't slide around unless you totally unscrewed it, at which point it would drop out the bottom onto the top of the tyre or maybe catch on a rim-brake mounting bolt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think by *steerer* you mean a *quill type stem*

[image: quill stems]

The diagonal cut part is a wedge. It's pulled up by a long bolt that runs down the stem and locks the stem in the fork steerer tube.